# class members restricted after converting to template

Tags: c++

So I'm working with templates and I've run into a problem. After I converted my code into templates I am no longer able to access the private members of my classes. I get the error that 'current' is a private member of 'Iterator'. So first I have each class:

```
template <class T>
struct nodeType {
    T info;
    nodeType<T> *link;
};

template <class T>
class Iterator {
public:
    Iterator();
    Iterator(nodeType<T> *);
    T operator*();
    bool IsNull();
    Iterator<T> operator++();
    Iterator<T> operator++(int);
    bool operator==(const Iterator<T> &) const;
    bool operator!=(const Iterator<T> &) const;
    Iterator<T> &operator=(T);
private:
    nodeType<T> *current;
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList {
public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList<T> &);
    ~LinkedList();
    void InsertHead(T);
    Iterator<T> InsertAfter(T, Iterator<T>);
    Iterator<T> Search(T);
    bool IsEmpty();
    void Print();
    void DestroyList();
    Iterator<T> Start();
    Iterator<T> End();
    const LinkedList<T> &operator=(const LinkedList<T> &);
private:
    nodeType<T> *head;
};
```

Before I used templates I used the following code, but not `current` is private and this no longer works.

```
template <class T>
Iterator<T> LinkedList<T>::InsertAfter(T input, Iterator<T> marker) {
    Iterator<T> newNode = new nodeType<T>;
    Iterator<T> findNode = marker;

    newNode = input;
    newNode.current->link = findNode.current->link;
    findNode.current->link = newNode.current;
    return findNode;
}
```

Then I tried to do the following and It get no errors but when I called the `InsertAfter` function to add a new item to the list it doesn't show up. I did a `cout` newNode = input; and it shows the value I want to insert, but the nodes don;t seem to connect up. Why can't I use the previous code I was doing before? Like `newNode.current->link = findNode.current->link;`

```
template <class T>
Iterator<T> Iterator<T>::operator++() {
    current = current->link;
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
Iterator<T> Iterator<T>::operator++(int) {
    Iterator<T> temp;

    temp = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return temp;
}

template <class T>
Iterator<T> LinkedList<T>::InsertAfter(T input, Iterator<T> marker) {
    Iterator<T> newNode = new nodeType<T>;
    Iterator<T> findNode = marker;

    newNode = input;
    newNode++ = findNode++;
    findNode++ = newNode;
    return findNode;
}
```

Comment: "Before I used templates". Where is your before-templates code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `newNode.current` within a member function of `LinkedList`, because `current` is private to `Iterator`. That's what `private` means - it is only accessible from member functions of the class it belongs in.

Clearly your "old" code was different. Possibly you had Iterator `friend` LinkedList in the old code. If you post your old code it might clear things up.